# Facebook API - Friends list response

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

How is the friends API response structured? The documentation explains it's an array of user objects and a total_count field. But what properties are included in the array objects? For example is it:

> ['id1','id2']

or

> [   {'name': 'A user name','id':'id1'},   {'name': 'Another user
>   name','id':'id2'} ]

I know it will be the friends who have already signed up for the app but the question is only about the structure of the response array and if you can select what fields to return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It´s JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "...",
      "id": "..."
    },
    {
      "name": "...",
      "id": "..."
    },
    {
      "name": "...",
      "id": "..."
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "next": "..."
  },
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 609
  }
}
```

You can test it in the API Explorer (if there are friends who authorized your App, or the API Explorer App: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends

Answer (score 0):

A friend is of type User so any field you can select from a User you can select for a friend.

In the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/friends) it states

> An array of User objects representing the person's friends with this additional field:

Clicking the User objects link will show https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/